# Trouble with Sort program using objects and constructors

Tags: java

Really new to java wanted to make my separate sorting methods (they all work hopefully i did them right)
Also very new to objects and constructors hopefully what im talking about is an object

so here are the constructors

```
public class sort{

    public int[] selectsort(int[] num)
{
    int j,i,key,min;

    for(j = 0; j<num.length; j++)
        {   
            key = num[j];
            min = j;
            for(i=j+1; i<num.length; i++)
            {
                if(num[i]<num[min])
                {
                    min = i;
                }
            }
                num[j] = num[min];
                num[min] = key;
        }
    return num;
}

public int[] insertsort(int[] num)
{
    int j,i,key;

    for(j = 1; j<num.length; j++)
        {   
            key = num[j];
            for(i=j-1; i>=0 && num[i]>key; i--)
            {
                num[i+1]=num[i];
            }

            num[i+1]=key;
        }

    return num;
}

public static int[] bubblesort(int[] num)
{
    int i,j,ini;

    for(i = num.length-1; i>1; i--)
        {
            for(j=0;j<i; j++)
            {
                if(num[j]>num[j+1])
                {
                    ini = num[j];
                    num[j]=num[j+1];
                    num[j+1]=ini;
                }
            }
        }
    return num;
}
}
```

and the program/test

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class sorttest{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] num = new int[]{9,1,4,5,6,2,3,7,8};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectsort(num)));
}
}
```

javac sort.java compiles but javac sorttest.java doesnt

error:

```
sorttest.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method selectsort(int[])
location: class sorttest
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectsort(num)));
                                       ^
```

1 error

Comment: I don't see any constructors (as your comment suggests), those are called methods. Due to the fact that they are not static, you must create an instance of `sort` (`sort instance = new sort()`) in order to invoke them (`instance.insertsort(integer_array)`). Judging from what you are trying to do though, it appears you want those methods to be static, in which you will invoke them directly from the class: `sort.insertsort(integer_array);`

Comment: Why does everyone post code with lowercase class names...

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions - Classes should be in upper camel case. Also please format your code properly. This is basically illegible. Good information [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: @Cruncher I agree, i think it's slowly driving me insane. Moreover I can't really be bothered to read code that's difficult to read.

Comment: ty i will try to change the formatting and such...just started coding 4 weeks ago and missed the last week of class where we discussed this..sorry for the poor formatting

Comment: @JoshM Thank You. Changed the methods to static and used the sort.insertsort(num) and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `selectsort` is not a part of the `sorttest` class - it's a `public static` method in the `sort` class. This means you need to qualify it by its class name:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class sorttest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = new int[]{9,1,4,5,6,2,3,7,8};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort.selectsort(num)));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a static import:

```
import static sort.selectsort;
import java.util.Arrays;   

public class sorttest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = new int[]{9,1,4,5,6,2,3,7,8};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectsort(num)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the first way is what i was looking for. Sorry if any of the code was messy